# Using msiexec on unattend.xml as SynchronousCommand but it run as asynchronous

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer, synchronous, unattend-file

I try to automatise my Windows configuration with unattend.xml file and during FirstLogonCommands, I only have SynchronousCommand block,

On theses blocks, i ran differents PowerShell scripts and inside one of them, i try to install .msi file but when msiexec is launch, the other blocks SynchronousCommand start simultaneously as asynchronous command.

But the normal process would be that these step should wait .msi is fully installed before continue their execution.

I already try :

- `cmd /c /start /wait msiexec myfile.msi`
- `start-process` with parameter `-wait` or `-noexit`
- `Start-Job -ScriptBlock` with a while `while ( ( get-job | where { $_.State -eq 'Running' -and $_.Command -like ('*'+$ScriptName+'*') } ).count -gt 0 )`...
- include msiexec command inside .bat file and run this .bat file with `cmd /c InstallMsi.bat`

None of these manipulations seems to works.

I think the problem is with msiexec execution....

Is anyone having already these issue?

Comment: It probably won't make a difference, but note that `cmd /c msiexec myfile.msi` is normally enough to achieve synchronous execution. When  you try that, does `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards indicate success (`0`), or an error (nonzero)?

Comment: Inside SynchronousCommand, when i try ```cmd /c msiexec myfile.msi```, it comes to an error because others next process run in same time, msiexec is not able to finish himself.

Comment: I assumed that `msiexec myfile.msi` was just a placeholder for your actual command line, but not that its syntax is invalid; you'd want `msiexec /i myfile.msi`, and `cmd /c msiexec /i myfile.msi` should execute synchronously - I don't know if its possible for a specific `.msi` to _itself_ exhibit asynchronous behavior (I've never heard of such a case). For instance, if I execute `cmd /c msiexec /i nosuch.msi; $LASTEXITCODE`, the error dialog blocks execution, and the value of `$LASTEXITCODE` - i.e. the process exit code - doesn't print until after the dialog is acknowledged and `msiexec` exits

Comment: Yes but before we have ```$LASTEXITCODE```, when process ```msiexec``` start running, the next steps are launched in same time that previous ```msiexec```. 
It's as if the ```msiexec``` process lost the parent child relationship between the synchronous processes.
When i ran the ```msiexec``` command alone, i don't have any problems, it's really when i use it inside unattend installation and when multiples steps are defined

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help with the `unattend.xml` part - is it an option to run _all_ MSI installations as part of a _single_ SynchronousCommand?

Comment: ```unattend.xml``` is a file who contains all the necessary configuration to setup my Windows Server installation (autologon account setup, hostname...) and inside this file, i use SynchronousCommand to execute differents things (PowerShell simple commands, shell commands, PowerShell scripts, also msiexec process to install ```.msi``` etc) in specific order (order who is broken when ```msiexec.exe``` is called)

Comment: So it sounds like you have _multiple_ SynchronousCommand steps, right? My question is if you put all MSI installations such as `cmd /c msiexec /i myfile.msi` in the _same_ step, does the problem go away?

Comment: No, i tried and the same behavior happens

Comment: you want to start `msiexec` in a do/until loop, and exit the loop when you can verify the MSI install has finished.

Comment: i tried to start it in do/until loop but in unattend setup context, i still have the same problem

Comment: @TheNurse, can you share the code you tried? I’m quite sure that if you start msiexec and then run a do/until with a sleep until it detects the msi package has been installed will be sufficient.

Comment: @alexzelaya, to run `msiexec` synchronously, i.e. to wait for the `msiexec` process to exit - which is what The Nurse trie - invoking it via `cmd /c` is sufficient, so there's no need for a polling loop - unless you're thinking of a different way to check for completion. Frankly, the symptoms mystify me, because they would imply that _PowerShell itself_ and possibly also batch-file execution suddenly became asynchronous in the context of a synchronous  `unattend.xml` command.

Comment: @mklement0 the script is just launching a process. If you open a cmd it will just open msiexec and exit. It won’t wait for it to finish and will just exit the cmd.

Comment: @alexzelaya, no it will wait; try `cmd /c msiexec`, which will show the command-line help GUI dialog. You'll see that the calling shell (whether it is PowerShell or `cmd.exe`) will not regain control until after the dialog is confirmed and `msiexec` has exited. It is only direct invocation (without `cmd /c`) that behaves asynchronously.